# I added @Valid annotation to my controller's register function and now I am getting a javax.validation.ValidationException error

Tags: java, json, validation, spring-mvc

This is what is being sent to the controller:

```
JSON: {"username":"testy9001@test.com","password":"test","firstName":"First","lastName":"Last","langKey":"en-US","enabled":false}
```

this is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody User userDTO) {
        User user = null;
        if (/* user authenticating */) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .body(error);
        } else {
            user = userService.createUserInformation(userDTO.getUsername().toLowerCase(), encoder.encode(userDTO.getPassword()), userDTO.getFirstName(), userDTO.getLastName(), userDTO.getLangKey());

            mailService.sendEmail(user, env.getRequiredProperty("default.mail."+env.getRequiredProperty("spring.profiles.active")+".url"), MailType.ACTIVATION);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

This issue started to occur once I pushed my app from my virtual machine to my staging server for testing. On my localhost the registration process works only on the staging server does it fail and return a 500 error.

```
Error: 2015-04-22 18:17:03.296 ERROR 6727 --- [-apr-443-exec-9] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter : Forwarding to error page from request [/register] due to exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
```

I am not sure what is causing this, I believe it to be the @Valid but I have removed during several and I still have gotten this error. Has anyone else experience a problem like this and if how were you able to correct the issue?

Comment: Hi, please provide the User class code

Comment: And also, can you please add a second argument, `BindingResult result` to the method and print out `result.getFieldError()` ? By this way you can check if it's about `@Valid` annotation.